# How can I change react-map-gl icons?

Tags: user-interface, icons, react-map-gl

I'm trying to customize my web application's map, I'm using react-map-gl (Uber opensource code) I try to change the map's icon pins but I could not figure out, what does the string code ICON mean?

import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

const ICON = `M20.2,15.7L20.2,15.7c1.1-1.6,1.8-3.6,1.8-5.7c0-5.6-4.5-10-10-10S2,4.5,2,10c0,2,0.6,3.9,1.6,5.4c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3
  c0,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.7,0.9c2.6,3.1,7.4,7.6,7.4,7.6s4.8-4.5,7.4-7.5c0.2-0.3,0.5-0.6,0.7-0.9
  C20.1,15.8,20.2,15.8,20.2,15.7z`;

const pinStyle = {
  cursor: 'pointer',
  fill: '#d00',
  stroke: 'none'
};

export default class CityPin extends PureComponent {

render() {
    const { size = 20, onClick } = this.props;

```
return (
  <svg
    height={size}
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    style={{ ...pinStyle, transform: `translate(${-size / 2}px,${-size}px)` }}
    onClick={onClick}
  >
    <path d={ICON} />
  </svg>
);
```

}
}

What does it mean all those numbers in ICON const? How can I change the style based on this code? Please help, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

All of the gibberish that is the ICON constant is [SVG Path notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) and is actually drawing your current symbol.  If you want to learn more about it, here is [another resource](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html).  There are even websites that can help you build your own SVG path string, [Option 1](https://mavo.io/demos/svgpath/) [Option 2](https://jxnblk.github.io/paths/), and searching the web will pull up many more.

Note that you likely need to update the viewbox numbers to fit your new thing once you have the symbol you want.  It otherwise chops off the symbol at those dimensions.

In trying to figure this out, my example update was:

`const ICON = 'm 10 35 l 15 30 l 15 -30 A 20 20 180 1 0 10 35 z'`

with a [viewbox in the svg tag](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/svg-viewbox-attribute/) of:

`viewBox="-8 0 55 65"`

EDIT::  you can also use any image as explained in the other answers.  There is an [article on using custom images at Medium](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/creating-custom-pins-with-react-mapbox-8b2c91a8659f) with a good explanation and more details.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you're using react-map-gl, so you could use the Marker component to change your icon pins.

Is there a specific image you'd like to use for your icons, say a .png file? If so, add that image to the directory called "public." Then, in your map where you create the markers, you can display this specific image.

For example, if you have an image called mapicon.png, you'd add that to your public folder. Then, when you're creating your markers, you could do something like this.

```
import ReactMapGL, {Marker} from 'react-map-gl';


<Marker key={} latitude={} longitude={}>
    <img
      src="mapicon.png"
      alt="map icon"
     />
</Marker>
```

From what I understand, the string is just a reference to where the icon image is stored. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom map marker with an SVG file. If you are using create-react-app, you can import your svg icon as a component like this:

```
import { ReactComponent as Pin } from '../../images/map-marker-icon.svg';
```

Then, in your example code above you can replace the

```
<path d={ICON} />
```

with this component. Here is an example:

```
export default class MapPin extends PureComponent {
  render() {
      <Marker  longitude={this.props.longitude} latitude=this.props.latitude}>
        <svg 
             onClick={() => onClick()}
             viewBox="0 0 60 100"
             enable-background="new 0 0 60 100">
          <Pin/>
        </svg>
      </Marker>
    ));
  }
}
```